# How to (Effectively) Achieve a Multi Bit Char Variable in C

Tags: c, string, char, cs50

I'd like to store the variable  (two spaces) in C.

It looks like there are no string data types in C, so how can I store such a value without having to create a `string s = get_string` function?

Comment: `char two_spc[2] = "  ";`

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C programming are built as arrays of chars.

In your case:
`char c[] = "  ";`

Comment: The above answer is sufficient. What I also generally do with C 'strings' is that I create a char buffer and stick that in a struct. I do this because structs can be assigned to each other and also passed and returned nicely from functions. You will still need to use sprintf to stuff it properly and you need to be sure you do not write of bounds (I have now said too much).

Comment: It's usually not the best idea unless you fully master what you're doing. Why? Because many will get confused about whether they're copying an address or the data it points to.

Comment: Thank you @yoones!

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations may define a `WCHAR_T` type, which is a `short` (2 bytes), and there'll be wide-string versions of many c-string functions (like `wcscmp` for `strcmp`) that take WCHAR_T* instead of char*.

Comment: `wchar_t` is required by the C Standard ; although some platforms make it 16-bit and some 32-bit